# Right expl3 data type and method to store and pass key-value style options to a LaTeX2e macro?

Tags: expl3, key-value

How can I store comma separated options in an `expl3` data type and then pass those options to a LaTeX2e macro?

Something like this (doesn't have to be a `clist`—I'm not sure what is the best data type to use.). In fact I strongly suspect I have no idea what I'm doing... :(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\textbf{What I want:}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=4cm,keepaspectratio,]{example-image.jpg}

\textbf{What I get:}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { width=0.3\linewidth , height=4cm , keepaspectratio }
\includegraphics[\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1, }]{example-image.jpg}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { foo=a, bar=b } \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\l_tmpa_tl]{example-image.jpg}`

Comment: As mentioned in the marked duplicate: `\use:x { \exp_not:N \includegraphics[\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , }] }{example-image.jpg}`.  @Manuel This surely works, but I'd guess that the `clist` was used on purpose.

Comment: @Manuel I guess that should be `\exp_after:wN \includegraphics \exp_after:wN [ \l_tmpa_tl ] { example-image-duck }`, as one should use the l3 names of the primitives. The overall usage of `\exp_after:wN` is discouraged though, if one can write what one wants to achieve using the `\exp_args` macros. So in this context, `\exp_last_unbraced:NNV \includegraphics [ \l_tmpa_tl ] { example-image-duck }` should be preferred.

Comment: @HenriMenke the `clist` was used, but the title is including "Right expl3 data type", so OP is not sure whether to use `clist` or something else, though I think a token list might be the wrong choice and a `clist` is better suited.

Comment: Thanks everyone, these are all very useful comments. I think I'll stick with the `clist` and use @HenriMenke's answer.